# Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Redirector could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel, paypal

Esto me sale cuando intento hacer una compra usando la librería de PayPal para Laravel, anteriormente me salió una compra, pero exactamente en el siguiente intento falló y ya no he podido hacerlo funcionar.

```
public function payment()
{
    $order = Order::find(session('order'));
    $cart = Cart::find(session('shopping_cart'));
    $data = [];
    $data['items'] = [
        [
            'name' => 'Pedido #' . $order->id,
            'price' => number_format($cart->total, 2, '.', ''), //API only supports two decimals
            'desc'  => 'Artículos',
            'qty' => $cart->items->count()
        ]
    ];
    $data['invoice_id'] = 'Testing1'; //$order->id;
    $data['invoice_description'] = " #{$data['invoice_id']} Invoice";
    $data['return_url'] = 'url';
    $data['cancel_url'] = 'url';
    $data['total'] = number_format($order->total, 2, '.', ''); //API only supports two decimals
    $data['shipping_discount'] = 0;

    $provider = new ExpressCheckout;
    $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);

    return redirect($response['paypal_link']);
}
```

Ese el código al que entra inmediatamente, el response no me regresa ninguna información valiosa para saber qué falló

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasé por lo mismo, esto pasa porque PayPal dentro de sus ambientes de pruebas y producción, usan las mismas registros de ID, veo que usas una cadena definida, por lo que está tratando de guardar un Invoice con un ID (ID interno de PayPal) que ya existe, por eso manda ese error.

Considera tener un formato diferente para los ID que uses en producción y pruebas, ya que si realizas una compra de prueba con el ID, digamos 9, y en producción, tus registros van en la 9, te va a causar el mismo error.

Trata de crear una función que tome el ambiente en el que estás trabajando y generes un ID único, para que en un futuro no se te lleguen a cruzar ningún identificador de tus ventas.

Aunque me parece un poco mal que PayPal, no diferencia el ID de las órdenes que hiciste en pruebas de las compras reales, esa es la solución hasta ahora.

Igualmente, para pruebas, el simple hecho de añadir un caracter cada que quieras hacer otra prueba, te va a funcionar. Pero lo ideal es generar ID's con formato para Producción y pruebas.